# update overall mean (review score) per day and subject

Tags: r

I have a dataset of several game reviews and I want to calculate the respective overall score each game had until the respective day - so basically the overall score a user saw on each given day.

The reviews are binary so it's just a vote up/down system where each 1 in the column positive marks an upvote:

```
game_id     created     positive
123         2018-07-18  1
123         2018-07-18  0
123         2018-07-18  1
123         2018-07-19  1 
456         2018-06-23  1
456         2018-06-25  1
456         2018-06-25  0
456         2018-06-26  1
789         2018-07-18  1
```

calculating the overall mean per day is easy with

```
group_by(game_id, created) %>% 
    summarise(sum(positive)/n()
```

but I'm struggling with how to include the reviews of the days before.

I want it to look like this:

```
game_id     created     total_score
123         2018-07-18  0.66
123         2018-07-19  0.75 
456         2018-06-23  1.0
456         2018-06-25  0.5
456         2018-06-26  0.66
789         2018-07-18  1
```

I thought about using combination of a loop and an if statement but am not really able to formulate it (and doubtful about its efficiency for larger datasets...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve it using `dplyr`. The key here is to create an intermediate computation of cumulative sums and then use those for the ratio:

```
df %>%
  group_by(game_id, created) %>%
  summarise(pos=sum(positive), tot=n()) %>%
  group_by(game_id) %>%
  mutate(pct = cumsum(pos) / cumsum(tot))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   game_id [3]
  game_id created      pos   tot   pct
    <int> <fct>      <int> <int> <dbl>
1     123 2018-07-18     2     3 0.667
2     123 2018-07-19     1     1 0.75 
3     456 2018-06-23     1     1 1    
4     456 2018-06-25     1     2 0.667
5     456 2018-06-26     1     1 0.75 
6     789 2018-07-18     1     1 1
```

Comment: might want to throw in an `arrange(created)` after the `summarise` line just for safety.

Comment: Good call, would it have to be `arrange(game_id, created)`? `dplyr` is not the first tool I grab for munging data.

Comment: cumsum, so obvious... why didn't I think of this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is named `df` you can:

```
library(dplyr)
df= arrange(df, game_id,created)    ## sort dataset
df$csum <- ave(df$positive, df$game_id, FUN=cumsum)  ## create cumulative sum
```

to create the cumulative sum up for each `game_id`. Make sure your dataframe is sorted by `game_id` and `created`